# Sending data from Arduino UNO as a SOAP request

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, servo, web-server, web-service

I have a servo motor on one end which can be turned ON and OFF with web service sending SOAP request. In the other end I have my Arduino UNO with ESP8266. Currently, I am able to send HIGH or LOW status from my Arduino to ESP8266.

My query is: After receiving the status "HIGH" from Arduino to ESP8266, I need to POST the status via SOAP request so that my motor would be "turned ON" . After turning ON the motor in the other end I would like to GET a simple SOAP response.

I am not sure if the above explains to you clearly but I am tired of thinking "how to do this".

Comment: Are you directly programming the ESP8266 with your own firmware, or are you communicating to it with AT commands?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I follow this tutorial (http://randomnerdtutorials.com/sending-data-from-an-arduino-to-the-esp8266-via-serial/) to send data from my board to ESP. But I am not sending "HI". Instead I am using two buttons, one for sending "HIGH" and other for "LOW".

Comment: OK, so you are programming the ESP8266 in Lua and that is where you want to implement your SOAP transmission. I am sorry, but this probably isn't the best place to help you. We can help with the Arduino programming, and with the ESP8266 if you were communicating with it using AT commands, or programming it with the Arduino IDE in C++. Not many people here will be versed enough in Lua to be able to help you.

Comment: SOAP, though, is just XML sent over an HTTP connection (although other connections can be used - you can even implement it as XML through email). The important thing is the XML. Since you only have two states - on and off - you can just pre-program the correct XML strings in your code and send them as a POST request to the remote end. How you would do that in Lua though is anyone's guess...

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How this can be done using Arduino IDE using AT commands or Arduino IDE in C++.? Is there any good references..? I also have a WSDL file for the other end Servo motor. Is there any use with that..?

Comment: @Majenko, Hi could you suggest me with something on how to proceed further.

Comment: Install the default AT command set firmware for the ESP8266 and you should be able to use this library on the Arduino: https://github.com/itead/ITEADLIB_Arduino_WeeESP8266

Comment: Support of SOAP occupies a lot of memory, it is better to use JSON-RPC ;)